# android parse JSON object

Tags: android, json, web-services, android-layout

On a web service I a, getting a json as follows in android application. I would likes to make a loop table view in android with lists object. Please help me how to make the loop. I successed by making table row. Still I am confusing with how to pass data

**My JSON**

```
   {
   "id":4,
   "access_token":"tge4sn1vdgbjcvvf",
   "session":1,
   "lists":[
      {
         "name":"name 1"
      },
      {
         "name":"name 2"
      },
      {
         "name":"name 3"
      },
      {
         "name":"name 4"
      },
      {
         "name":"name 4"
      }
   ]
}
```

**My Code**

```
 if (response != null) {
     InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); 

     String a = convertStreamToString(in);

     JSONObject jsono = stringToJsonobj(a);

     String passedStringValue = jsono.getString("session");



if(passedStringValue.equals("1")){ 
     // I want the loop here
     // Tried this - myListsAll=jsono.getJSONObject("lists");
    }
```

Any one please help me how to parse this data
Thanks in advance

Comment: That is because the name is present in the data object, which happens to be an JSONArray. Get the data array from the response object, traverse through each JSONObject in the array, and from each object, extract your name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lists is JSONArray instead of JSONObject.currently you are trying to get it as an JSONObject.you can iterate through lists JSONArray as:

```
if(passedStringValue.equals("1")){ 

   JSONArray myListsAll=jsono.getJSONArray("lists");

   for(int i=0;i<myListsAll.length();i++){

    JSONObject jsonobject=myListsAll.getJSONObject(i);

     // get name from jsonobject object
     String str_name=jsonobject.optString("name");
  }

}
```